# Find zeroes to be flipped so that number of consecutive 1’s is maximized

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Find zeroes to be flipped so that number of consecutive 1’s is maximized.

```
Input:   arr[] = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}
     m = 2
Output:  5 7
```

We are allowed to flip maximum 2 zeroes. If we flip
arr[5] and arr[7], we get 8 consecutive 1's which is
maximum possible under given constraints .

Now if we were to find just the maximum number of 1's that is possible, is it possible to solve using dynamic programming approach?

Comment: You can use dynamic programming, but it would be asymptotically better to solve it using two pointer technique or binary search.

Comment: @SatyendraKumar this problem can be solved in time O(N)

Comment: @SatyendraKumar Hint is using extra space and you can crack this in as fast as linear time.

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Comment: If DP is not applicable for this question, can someone explain why DP will not be useful here..If we could find the Maximum countOne sub-array with at most 'm' zeroes, then the answer will be Length of this subarray + (m - number of zeroes in this subarray). This shows symmetry with Maximum Sum Sub-array problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use sliding window concept here - use start and end vars to store index of range. Whenever you encounter a 0, increment the counter of zeros received. Include it in current length.. If zeros encounter equals m+1, increment start till you encounter 0.

```
public static int[] zerosToFlip(int[] input, int m) {
        if (m == 0) return new int[0];
        int[] indices = new int[m];
        int beginIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = 0;
        int maxBeginIndex=0;
        int maxEndIndex=0;
        int zerosIncluded = input[0] == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (input[i] == 0) {
                if (zerosIncluded == m) {
                    if (endIndex - beginIndex > maxEndIndex - maxBeginIndex){
                        maxBeginIndex = beginIndex;
                        maxEndIndex = endIndex;
                    }
                    while (input[beginIndex] != 0) beginIndex++;
                    beginIndex++;
                } else {
                    zerosIncluded++;
                }
            }
            endIndex++;
        }

        if (endIndex - beginIndex > maxEndIndex - maxBeginIndex){
            maxBeginIndex = beginIndex;
            maxEndIndex = endIndex;
        }
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = maxBeginIndex; i <= maxEndIndex; i++) {
            if (input[i] == 0) {
                indices[j] = i;
                ++j;
            }
        }
        return indices;
    }
```

Comment: I know the sliding window solution, but I am looking for a DP solution.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in **linear time O(N)** and **linear space O(N)**. Its not *full fledged dynamic programming*, but its similar to that as it uses **precomputation.**

**Data Structures Used:**

**`1.left`**: It is an integer array, of same length as given array. It is precomputed such that **`for every position i`**:

`left[i] = Number of consecutive 1's to the left position i`

**`2.right`**: It is an integer array, of same length as given array. It is precomputed such that **`for every position i`**:

`right[i] = Number of consecutive 1's to the right position i`

These can be computed in `single traversal` of the array.Assuming `arr` is the original array, following pseudocode does the job:

Pseudocode for populating `left array`

```
left()
{
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i < arr length; ++i)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                left[i] = 0;
                if(arr[i] == 1)
                 count++;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                left[i] = count;
                if(arr[i] == 1)
                 count++;
                else count = 0;
            }
        }
}
```

Pseudocode for populating `right array`

```
right()
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = arr length - 1;i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if(i == arr length - 1)
        {
            right[i] = 0;
            if(arr[i] == 1)
             count++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            right[i] = count;
            if(arr[i] == 1)
             count++;
            else count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Now the only thing we have to do is :check all pair of positions i and j `(i < j)` such that `arr[i] = 0` and `arr[j] = 0` and for no position between i and j arr[i] should be 0 and Keep track of the pair for which we get maximum value of the following:**

**`left[i] + right[j] + right[l]`**

**You could also use `left[i] + right[j] + left[r]`**.

`left[i]` tells the number of consecutive 1's to the left of position `i` and `right[j]` tells the number of consecutive 1's to the right of position `j` and the number of consecutive 1's between `i` and `j` can be counted be `left[r] OR right[l]`, and therefore, we have two candidate expressions.

**This can also be done in single traversal, using following pseudocode:**

```
max_One()
  {
    max = 0;
    l = -1, r = -1;
    for(int i = 0;i < arr length; ++i)
    {
     if(arr[i] == 0)
     { 
        if(l == -1)
         l = i;
        else
        {
            r = i;          
            if(left[l] + right[r] + right[l] > max)
            {
                max = left[l] + right[r] + right[l];                
                left_pos = l;
                right_pos = r;
            }
            l = r;
        }
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: This solution will work only in case of m=2,..(i.e. we are allowed to flip only two zeroes to one ). Or did I miss something.